# Peak vs average maximum charging current for li-ion battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I'm working on a circuit for charging 18650 battery packs. I know that for the longest battery life possible, 18650 batteries should be charged at < 1C during the constant current charge regime. However, is this a maximum limit that shouldn't be exceeded at all to avoid damage or is it possible to provide a higher current over short periods so that the average charging current remains < 1C?

Say that I had a 1 Ah li-ion battery pack that needs to be charged at 1 A. Would there be any difference in terms of battery reliability/lifetime if I charge this battery pack at 1 A at 100% duty cycle versus, say, 2 A at 50% duty cycle with a short period like 1 ms.

Also I know that there are ICs that take care of this entire process, but my application means I have to use a less integrated/discrete solution.

Answer (score 0):

For li-based batteries the recommended charging current is between 0.1 to 1C where C is the capacity.

> However, is this a maximum limit that shouldn't be exceeded at all to avoid damage or is it possible to provide a higher current over short periods so that the average charging current remains < 1C?

This depends on couple of things such as:

- Initial state of charge (SoC) therefore the initial pack/cell voltage
- Construction
- Environment (temperature)

For deeply discharged batteries the charging process shouldn't start with the nominal current (e.g. 0.5C) instantly. A process called "trickle charge" should be followed first which is basically to apply smaller charging current for relatively shorter periods to bring the battery to an acceptable condition before switching to nominal constant current charging.

Increasing the charge current periodically may trigger some chemical reactions inside the battery. These reactions are local i.e. happen at some, say, micrometre-cube areas, and cause local temperature rises at multiple points which simply reduce the lifetime.

The overall construction and environment are important. Simply, high temperature reduces the lifetime. If the battery pack comes with a protection board (e.g. those popular DW01-based ones) then higher charge current may increase the board's temperature due to the external MOSFETs. Depending on the mounting location this board may cause a local temperature rise somewhere on the battery/cell/pack, therefore reduce the lifetime.

Also, a battery's output resistance tends to increase as the battery approaches its end of life. Higher charge current will simply dissipate higher power across this resistance therefore will cause higher temperature rise which will further decrease the lifetime.

Some batteries may not be happy with 1C, some of them may allow even higher charging currents with less than, say, 5°C of temperature rise. 0.5 ~ 1C is somewhat a "sweet spot", if you like – brings less temperature rise with an acceptable charging time.

---

It should also be noted that the entire charging process is **not** something like "apply a pre-set constant current until the voltage reaches its recommended maximum". The charging current should be reduced gradually as the pack/cell voltage increases. For safety reasons the temperature should also be monitored.